# Launch Android SDK manager - Tools directory doesn't exist? Mac

Tags: android, sdk, launch

I'm on mac, I think I've done everything right so far. following these instructions:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

it says to navigate to tools/ directory in terminal. Here are my steps.

1. Open terminal
2. cd Applications
   result is: No such file or directory

path to my tools directory is as follows

```
Applications->adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219  ->SDK -> tools
```

I tried putting my folder onto my desktop, both the tools folder, and my adt-bundle because I could change directory to my desktop, and when I enter ls to the terminal I see my tools folder, and my adt-bundle is there,

but the problem is when I try to enter

cd tools

or

cd adt-bundle(etc...)

it says that it is not a directory.

what do I do?

Comment: if your path is /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219 then launch `/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools/android`

Comment: What do you mean "launch" Do I enter the command as follows? launch /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools/android   ??? Or does launch mean "change directory?"

Comment: at the Terminal shell prompt ($), just type `/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools/android` and press <ENTER>.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recently encountered this issue, and figured I'd post on this for clarification or for anyone still encountering it.

It seems you have to be at the root of the `/adt-bundle-mac-VERSION/sdk`directory in order to execute the "android" command. 
I normally cd into the directory until I reach the location of the command, but in this case I encountered the same issue as the original poster.

You must use the tab key to the android command... 
ie...

locate your installation `/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk` hit TAB key `/tools` hit TAB key `/android`

instead of `cd adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/` `cd/sdk` `cd/tools` `android`

If done properly the SDK manager should launch for you.

Hope this helps anybody out there.

Comment: Think adding Android SDK to your path brings the same results as I understand you right - the benefit is that android and that other cli commands are available from every dir.

Answer (score 20):

Go to this directory:

```sh
cd /adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
```

and run:

```sh
./android
```

Comment: this is actually not wrong, just need clarification to make it more useful

Comment: worked fine for me. Obviously whoever reads this must set the right path in order for this to work.

Comment: This does work although the path is incorrect but the key difference here is prefixing ./

Thanks

Comment: The android command is no longer available.For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio. For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

Answer (score 8):

You can launch the SDK Manager by using the GUI:

- Launch Android Studio
- Create a new blank project
- In the toolbar, look for the icon with tooltip "SDK Manager"

[image: SDK Manager button in toolbar]

Answer (score 7):

A lot of answers have been given here that you should go to *`/{path-to-your-android-sdk}/tools`*
and run *`./android`*.

For me, this did not work. When I opened the *`android`* file located at my *`/{path-to-your-android-sdk}/tools`* directory with a text editor, it contained the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo The "android" command is no longer available.
echo For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
echo For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
exit 1
```

So the right approach now, is as stated by @Shijil in his comment.

In the directory for your android sdk, you should use:

For SDK Manager:

```
cd tools
cd bin
./sdkmanager
```

For AVD Manager:

```
cd tools
cd bin
./avdmanager
```

**NB** For the last command in each of the options above, you will have to supply additional args depending on the operation you want to perform. An example arg that works for both is `--list`. Running the commands without any args will only display the possible args you could have passed.

*Personally, I think using the GUI in android studio is easier. Especially for linux beginners.*

Answer (score 6):

Use `cd /users/user/...your path.../android-sdk/tools`

and then :

`./android`

Answer (score 5):

Here is your "tools" directory for Android Studio in OS X El Captain(Yosemite also has the same path hopefully):

```
Users/user-name/Library/Android/sdk/tools
```

In the terminal, just type: `Library/Android/sdk/tools`
and hit enter. And you are in the tools folder.

Please note that `user-name` refers to the mac user

Answer (score 4):

Better open terminal and type `which android`.

It will tell you the path where you have the package installed.

Then yeah, you just have to execute that path on the terminal.

Your android package might have been installed with Homebrew or others, so the path can be different.

Edit: typo

Answer (score 1):

For me the directory was `cd /Users/your_user_name/Library/Android/sdk/tools/`
and after that the command was `./android list targets`
I hope this can help