# How do I open the sdk manager in the Mac

Tags: android-studio, sdk

How do I open the sdk manager in the Mac system to download the missing files for android studio

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40511169/7137248

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just cd into the installed SDK path like this

```
cd /Users/<mac-user>/<path to sdk folder>/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager
```

Where `<mac-user>` is your username to the MAC

For example:

```
 cd /Users/user/android-sdk-macosx/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager
```

**OLD ANSWER**

```
  cd /Users/<mac-user>/<path to sdk folder>/tools && ./android
```

where `<mac-user>` is your username to the MAC

For example in my own case, executing the following opens the SDK manager for me

```
 cd /Users/user/android-sdk-macosx/tools && ./android
```

Comment: When using this today I get error: The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

Comment: That's right, "android" is deprecated now. You can run `cd /Users/<mac-user>/<path to sdk folder>/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager` and it will work fine. From there, just follow Android documentation with the desired comments. E.g.: `cd /Users/<mac-user>/<path to sdk folder>/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager --list`

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Android Studio 3.4.2

The SDK Manager does not show up under the Tools menu, but it is available as an icon on the upper right hand menu. It's a cube with a blue arrow pointing down.

Answer (score 6):

./android is not available now.

> The "android" command is deprecated. For manual SDK, AVD, and project
>   management, please use Android Studio. For command-line tools, use
>   tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

```
admindeMacBook-Pro-3:sdk gongzelong$ cd tools/
admindeMacBook-Pro-3:tools gongzelong$ ./android 
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

admindeMacBook-Pro-3:tools gongzelong$ ./bin/sdkmanager 
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
```

We could use `./SDK_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager` instead.

```
admindeMacBook-Pro-3:tools gongzelong$ ./bin/sdkmanager --help
Usage: 
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file=<file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --version

With --install (optional), installs or updates packages.
    By default, the listed packages are installed or (if already installed)
    updated to the latest version.
With --uninstall, uninstall the listed packages.

    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
    with explicit paths.

With --update, all installed packages are updated to the latest version.

With --list, all installed and available packages are printed out.

With --licenses, show and offer the option to accept licenses for all
     available packages that have not already been accepted.

With --version, prints the current version of sdkmanager.

Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK 
                              containing this tool

    --channel=<channelId>: Include packages in channels up to <channelId>.
                           Common channels are:
                           0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary).

    --include_obsolete: With --list, show obsolete packages in the
                        package listing. With --update, update obsolete
                        packages as well as non-obsolete.

    --no_https: Force all connections to use http rather than https.

    --proxy=<http | socks>: Connect via a proxy of the given type.

    --proxy_host=<IP or DNS address>: IP or DNS address of the proxy to use.

    --proxy_port=<port #>: Proxy port to connect to.

    --verbose: Enable verbose output.

* If the env var REPO_OS_OVERRIDE is set to "windows",
  "macosx", or "linux", packages will be downloaded for that OS.
```

Comment: showing the output for `--help` argument actually enlightened me, thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can open the SDK manager in the terminal: android -v

Comment: Please click on android exec file in the tools folder to open android sdk manager.

Answer (score 3):

It can be found inside Android Studio.
See here...

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Answer (score 2):

## 2019 Updated Answer

This thread pointed me in the right direction and hope this answer will help other recent visitors like me:

To access **sdkmanager**:

`cd /Users/<mac-user>/<path to sdk folder>/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager`

From there, just follow the documentation, e.g.:

`cd /Users/<mac-user>/<path to sdk folder>/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager --list`

or

`cd /Users/<mac-user>/<path to sdk folder>/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager --update`

**sdkmanager** documentation:

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer but maybe it will help someone: When I had already installed sdk manager in `sdk/tools/bin` but `sdkmanager` command did not work I've added these lines to `.bash_profile` and it started works good:

```
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/sdkmanager:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you saw this, but I spotted the tools in library.
So, go to your file manager and show all hidden files by using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>

Then follow this path:
*/Users/youruserDon'tforget/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin*
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of start of 2024 all the answers here are outdated and the sdkmanager now appears to live in:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager
```

once you have installed using, ironically enough using the "SDK Manager" in Android Studio tools menu, the "Android Command-line Tools (latest)" [sic] package under the "SDK Tools" tab.

Answer (score -2):

Just go to Android Studio > Tools > AVD Manager

And install/create your simulator

Comment: This question is about the SDK manager, not the emulator and the accompanying AVD manager.